# kubuntu upgrade to 16.04.1 system no longer boots to login panel

Tags: 16.04

Upgrading from Kubuntu 14.04 directly to Kubuntu 16.04 following the point 1 
release results in a system which does not boot to the login panel but a blank screen.

Following other suggestions on this topic - there have been no additions to /etc/profile.d and the ~/.Xauthority is owned by me.

I really need a solution to this.

A work around (of sorts) is to get a console session (ctrl-alt-f1), login and enter "startx".

Comment: I don't know how your partitions are set. If you set your /home in a separate partition, you can reinstall the latest version of Ubuntu 16.04 on top of what you already have.  Just don't format the /home partition or any other data or Windows partition.  There is a good chance that the reinstall will fix the problem. It never seemed to hurt my system. But no guarantees it will make the repair.  While it works for me most of the time, there have been exceptions where it did not fix itself and I had to replace the home partition as well.

Comment: Good idea. Unfortunately /home is not in a separate partition on my system.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that. I learned that lesson the hard way.  I had to buy a new drive and set up the partitions and copy the /home folder into the /home partition manually to save anything. Since then, I always separate my home folder.  I wish I had a computer that allowed more drives so I could have two additional drives including a second one for a home and mirror.